# I need to change tablet OS to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, login, windows-10, tablet

I recently purchased an RCA Cambio 2-in-1 that came with Windows 10.
Last week, I booted up the device and was just taken to Automatic Startup Repair and it wants me to login to my local user a/c.
Because I've been using just signing in with the PIN, I've forgotten my password and can't login. I tried resetting the password online, but it's not being accepted on the device - maybe a local a/c on the device.

I just can't get in.

I've searched and searched for a solution; contacted RCA and they've not responded; asked on the forums but no luck.

All my other devices are either Linux or Ubuntu and I'd be happy to shift to either. I can access the BIOS and would like to know if I can somehow boot the device using Linux and somehow change the Windows local a/c password to login (if I have to continue using Windows)

Would really appreciate some help on this, pls.

Some snapshots of the BIOS: [BIOS Snapshots](https://link.shutterfly.com/0NFeuqJASab)

Comment: You would like to install Ubuntu, fair enough. But in reality, it seems this question is about how to get access to your current Windows installation. Maybe edit the question so it only covers: How to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled to get a solution and in doing, was guided to [INSTALL LINUX on an RCA Cambio! IT IS POSSIBLE!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuOXEJO9wm4)
Here I saw that someone had actually managed to install Linux on this particular tablet and he's been very kind to share his experiences and challenges and so have others who have posted therein.
Using this method, I succeeded in booting the device using a Linux Mint LXDE USB and from there I used the CHNTPW method to remove the forgotten Windows 10 password.
Thereafter when I rebooted the device and was brought back to Startup Repair, I was now not required to put in a password and thereafter successfully reset the device.

ALHAMDULILLAH.

Answer (score 0):

First use another computer to do this: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
Then plug the USB stick (Flash Drive) into the tablet
On the boot tab of your BIOS select your USB Stick (Flash Drive) (This will usually contain the brand name eg. Sandisk or a name like "Generic USB Device" or "Generic Storage Device")
Go through the Ubuntu Installer and you're done!

Comment: Thanks. I did this and booted the tablet.In the BIOS I can see the USB as a bootable option (which I select) but doesn't boot the tab from the USB. Just jumps to Windows Startup Repair or EFI shell(whichever I set as 2nd option). Tried booting my PC with the USB and boots fine, so USB is OK.

Comment: I have also tried increasing the Setup Prompt Timeout and disabling Quiet Boot, but no luck.
Also set the OS IMAGE ID to Android but no luck.
Somehow Windows is forcing it's way in.

Comment: Did you make sure to set the Flash drive as the default boot device and save your settings? You can also try disabling secure boot.